# ejabberd s2s to GTalk/Hangout with TLS

Tags: ssl, encryption, xmpp, ejabberd, google-talk

From what I can tell, in all my searching and tests, if I set up my own jabber server (using ejabberd) I can not do s2s with TLS to and from google XMPP servers.

When I connect, the ejabberd log records:

```
I(<0.377.0>:ejabberd_s2s_out:365) : Connection established: XXXX.net -> gmail.com with TLS=false
```

Is it even possible to do S2S TLS with google XMPP servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Google does not support TLS on server-to-server connections today, it was turned off some years ago. See for example [this mailing list post](http://mail.jabber.org/pipermail/operators/2012-April/001366.html).

It used to work, but there has been no official word on why it was disabled, or whether it might return.

Comment: An additional note:  Since the change of Talk to Hangouts, Google no longer supports s2s connections **period**.

Comment: Not quite true. Google still supports s2s. However messages sent to Google users that are using Hangouts get silently discarded. Try connecting to Google using a standard XMPP client, you'll find you can still communicate with users on other servers (as long as they don't require encryption - many do, since May this year).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It is my understanding that they will be phasing out Talk and removing the functionality from Gmail, too.